# Linq: How can I get a result in a grouping query which is value agnostic and has dynamic columns?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have a table called Foo and I have two columns: Lorem and Ipsum, so the scheme of the table is:

```
Foo(Lorem, IpsumID)
```

I also have a table called IpsumTypes, which looks like this:

```
IpsumTypes(IpsumID, IpsumName)
```

I would like to write a LINQ query which will have the following result:

**Headers: Lorem, IpsumName1, IpsumName2, ..., IpsumNamen
Values: Loremi, count(IpsumName1), ..., count(IpsumNamen)**

Each row represents a group of Lorem value and the number of each possible IpsumID in the group. New rows can be added to the IpsumTypes table, rows can be deleted too, so I need dynamically generated columns, because at the time of writing the code I'm not aware of the possible values of Ipsum. How can I achieve this? Is there a magical Linq query which solves this problem, or should I get the values from the database and parse them separately, if speed counts?

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: I think some sample (invented) data would really help put this into context... personally I'm thinking the answer lies with appropriate use of `.ToLookup()` and `.ToDictionary()`...

Comment: Data can be anything, that's why the answer is difficult to find, at least for me. We don't know the number of columns of the result, we don't know the rows of IpsumTypes.

Comment: So how would you like it represented in C#? As dictionary? List? custom object??

Comment: I'm using Visual Basic, but an IEnumerable would be nice.

Comment: This answer of yours tells me you know nothing about .NET. You should learn something about .NET first before you start jumping around LINQ.

Comment: @Lajos - even though it might be "anything", a concrete example would really help! Also, I suspect you should really be handling the pivot / presentation *at the UI*, so the structure is actually very simple. That way you *do* know the number of columms - it is probably 3 - it is just a matter of twisting it at the app-tier (which is much better suited to this than the DB is). Again; sample data please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query gets the values you want out of the database.  From there, you can project into xml or some other dynamic shape that your program can understand.

```
from foo in Foo
let name = foo.IpsumType.IpsumName
group foo by new
{
  Lorem = foo.Lorem,
  Name = name
} into g
select new
{
  Lorem = g.Key.Lorem,
  Name = g.Key.Name,
  Count = g.Count()
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) SQL statement. But there is no LINQ equivalent, so you should use SQL instead and parse the returned data yourself.